# How to bypass ajax url request error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My app has a Save button, when the data is input after a validation, there is an ajax function to call the web service to return some values for user to select (either add new record or update the exist one). It works perfectly until our business rule changed :if the web service is down the app must save whatever the data user input. What should I do to resume the saving or ignore the error if the URL request is unsuccessful? Currently, it just shuts down and pop up only the alert I put in , not update nor save the data at all. Thank you,

I update my code below:

- In the Page_load, the validate() function is call:

  ```
  cmdSave.Atttributes.Add("onclick", "return Validate()");

    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {        

        //Do the Save stuff here
  }
  ```
- This is my jquery:

  ```
  function Validate(){
      Validate data here.....

      Return_Address();
  }

  function Return_Address(){
       $.ajax({                
          type: "POST",                                       
          url: "https://www.wrongyahoo.com/",
          data: obj,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (results){
             Do something ....
          },
          error: function(xhr){
             alert("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
             //As Michele suggested below, I save the values in local variables for saving later
             newAddress = $("#Address").val();
          }
  }
  ```

How do I resume back to the Validate() to continue saving if the ajax is fail?

Comment: Without a code example I'm not sure how you are trying or would want to try to handle it.  Seems the simplest way would be to put in an error function for the ajax call per http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

Save data in localstorage and recognizing network status you can start another ajax request when the connection is available again, then clean data from localstorage.